# I have Imported AVFoundation and added Audio to my app but if the App enters the background mode the audio isn't stop

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swift3, avaudioplayer

I have Imported AVFoundation and added Audio to my app but if the App enters the background mode the audio doesn't stop

```
var backgroundMusic: AVAudioPlayer? = {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Mining by Moonlight", withExtension: "mp3") else {
        return nil
    }
    do {
        let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player.numberOfLoops = -1
        return player
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}()
```

In `viewDidLoad` is the code:

```
backgroundMusic?.prepareToPlay()

backgroundMusic?.play()
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you create a global variable of avAudioPlayer, If not then make and stop audioplayer in class appDelegate, method: ApplicationDidEnterInBackground...I hope.....

Answer (score 0):

make sure that Audio and AirPlay is not enabled in your background tasks

Answer (score 0):

Use  NSNotificationCenter  in your controller class

```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:   Selector(“stopSong:"), name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
```

If Your app is running in background than use this method

```
  func stopSong(notification : NSNotification) {
  backgroundMusic?.stop()
   }
```